# How do I handle selection in NavigationView on macOS correctly?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I want to build a trivial macOS application with a sidebar and some contents according to the selection in the sidebar.

I have a MainView which contains a `NavigationView` with a `SidebarListStyle`. It contains a `List` with some `NavigationLink`s. These have a binding for a selection.

I would expect the following things to work:

1. When I start my application the value of the selection is ignored. Neither is there a highlight for the item in the sidebar nor a content in the detail pane.
2. When I manually select an item in the sidebar it should be possible to navigate via up/down arrow keys between the items. This does not work as the selection / highlight disappears.
3. When I update the value of the selection-binding it should highlight the item in the list which doesn't happen.

Here is my example implementation:

```swift
enum DetailContent: Int, CaseIterable {
    case first, second, third
}
extension DetailContent: Identifiable {
    var id: Int { rawValue }
}

class NavigationRouter: ObservableObject {
    @Published var selection: DetailContent?
}

struct DetailView: View {
    @State var content: DetailContent
    @EnvironmentObject var navigationRouter: NavigationRouter

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(content.rawValue)")
            Button(action: { self.navigationRouter.selection = DetailContent.allCases.randomElement()!}) {
                Text("Take me anywhere")
            }
        }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}

struct MainView: View {
    @ObservedObject var navigationRouter = NavigationRouter()
    @State var detailContent: DetailContent? = .first

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Section(header: Text("Section")) {
                    ForEach(DetailContent.allCases) { item in
                        NavigationLink(
                            destination: DetailView(content: item),
                            tag: item,
                            selection: self.$detailContent,
                            label: { Text("\(item.rawValue)") }
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
            .frame(minWidth: 250, maxWidth: 350)
        }
            .environmentObject(navigationRouter)
            .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .onReceive(navigationRouter.$selection) { output in
                self.detailContent = output
            }
    }
}
```

The `EnvironmentObject` is used to propagate the change from inside the `DetailView`. If there's a better solution I'm very happy to hear about it.

So the question remains:
What am I doing wrong that this happens?
I had some hope that with Xcode 11.5 Beta 1 this would go away but that's not the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After finding the [tutorial from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/creating-a-macos-app) it became clear that you don't use `NavigiationLink` on macOS. Instead you bind the list and add two views to `NavigationView`.

With these updates to `MainView` and `DetailView` my example works perfectly:

```swift
struct DetailView: View {
    @Binding var content: DetailContent?
    @EnvironmentObject var navigationRouter: NavigationRouter

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(content?.rawValue ?? -1)")
            Button(action: { self.navigationRouter.selection = DetailContent.allCases.randomElement()!}) {
                Text("Take me anywhere")
            }
        }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}

struct MainView: View {
    @ObservedObject var navigationRouter = NavigationRouter()
    @State var detailContent: DetailContent?

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(selection: $detailContent) {
                Section(header: Text("Section")) {
                    ForEach(DetailContent.allCases) { item in
                        Text("\(item.rawValue)")
                            .tag(item)
                    }
                }
            }
                .frame(minWidth: 250, maxWidth: 350)
                .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
            DetailView(content: $detailContent)
        }
            .environmentObject(navigationRouter)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            .onReceive(navigationRouter.$selection) { output in
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(200)) {
                    self.detailContent = output
                }
            }
    }
}
```